# gdi+ error saving image from console application

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, gdi

I know this question has been answered earlier but somehow I cannot resolve the issue from the available solutions.

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(@"D:\test\6.png", FileMode.Open))
                { 
                    var path = @"D:\test1\";
                    using (var image = Image.FromStream(stream))
                    {
                        var newWidth = (int)(image.Width * 0.5);
                        var newHeight = (int)(image.Height * 0.5);
                        var thumbnailImg = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight);
                        var thumbGraph = Graphics.FromImage(thumbnailImg);
                        thumbGraph.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        thumbGraph.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                        thumbGraph.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        var imageRectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight);
                        thumbGraph.DrawImage(image, imageRectangle);
                        thumbnailImg.Save(path, image.RawFormat);
                    }
            }
```

When I run the following code I get an error as

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll**

Additional information: A generic error occurred in GDI+.

Comment: What is your 'path' variable set to? Just in case its trying to overwrite the same image which is currently in use by the FileStream.
Also, the newWidth and newHeight I hope is larger than 0 :-)
Last thing: Make sure that the input 6.png isnt corrupted in any way.

Comment: I have edited my post for the path variable.The newWidth and newHeight are all greater than zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path variable does not point to an actual filename and just a folder name. That is your problem. :)

If you change it to

```
 var path = @"D:\test1\newImage.bmp";
```

or similar it should work. (change the extension into something that matches your output image format)